# Outputting each value in array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this foreach loop nested inside a while loop:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['arrayPoints'] as $value) { 
echo $value;
}
```

This outputs the all the values stored in the array, 543216 as shown below, but as the foreach loop is in the while loop, 543216 is repeated until there are no more rows:

[image: TEST DATA- output of the foreach loop shown (543216)]

I need the foreach loop to output each value in the array separately for each row.

So for example (using the image above and the array values of 543216):
I need the output to show 5 for the first row, then 4 for the second row, 3 for the 3rd row, 2 fourth row and so on (as shown below).

```
Dave Jackson |TEXT BOX| |DROP-DOWN| 5
Bobby Brown |TEXT BOX| |DROP-DOWN| 4
Daniel Grey |TEXT BOX| |DROP-DOWN| 3
Richard Green |TEXT BOX| |DROP-DOWN| 2
David Bolt |TEXT BOX| |DROP-DOWN| 1
Jason Moore |TEXT BOX| |DROP-DOWN| 6
```

How can this be done?

EDIT:

```
print_r($_SESSION['arrayPoints']);
```

outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 4 [2] => 3 [3] => 2 [4] => 1 [5] => 6 )
```

-The While loop: `while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {` is a query fetch action.

-Each row shown in the image above is in order with each number in the array. So first row = 5 , second row = 4 and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's in _what_ `while` loop? Please post more of the surrounding relevant code. In particular, if the while loop is a query fetch action, please also tell us how the values in `$_SESSION['arrayPoints']` relate to the values being fetched in the while loop.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I have made edit to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code says that you want to print every number for each data fetched from DB, which is not what you want. You want a single number printed for each data. So forget the foreach. What you need is:

```
echo $_SESSION['arrayPoints'][$i];
```

where $i is the current row being fetched (you need to set and increment it).

Comment: this is that I have done 

`$i = 0;
echo $_SESSION['arrayPoints'][$i]; 
$i++;`

This outputs the first number stored in the array only. Is my syntax and logic correct?

Comment: You must initialize $i before the loop, otherwise it will be set to 0 everytime.

Comment: I had a problem in initialising $i, how would the syntax to comment above look like?

Comment: `$i = 0; while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {...`

Comment: So I put the `$i = 0` outside the while loop and i `echo $_SESSION['arrayPoints'][$i];` It outputs nothing, I increment it inside the while loop `$i++` and it still outputs nothing

Comment: Yesterday you said it was working, I can't help you if you modified your code since then.

Comment: I have made no modification since, I thought it was working but I was looking at wrong output ':D

Comment: Update your question with full code in a single code block.

Comment: $j++ should be after the echo, otherwise you will not increment it after each row.